# Instantiate Class with Constructor

Tags: c#, .net

In C# How does one instantiate a separate class when using an abstract class?
I'm trying to instantiate foo3.

Meaning:

```
abstract class foo
{
     public string myId {get;set;}
     public string mystring {get;set;}
     public foo3 my3rdFoo {get;set}
}

class foo2 : foo
{
     public string myFavoriteFoo {get;set;}
}

class foo3
{
     public string myName{get;set}         
}
```

After creating a new foo2 succesfully....(I didn't add the code.)

Im trying to call foo3 using the code below:

```
((foo2)newDoc).foo3.myName = "blah...blah...";
```

But I keep getting a null error....here...

Comment: foo3 is null perhaps?

Comment: Right but how do I instantiate it?  I edited my question.  Thanks...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in this last line? Are you declaring your class to be foo2 and accessing foo3 as a property from inside your foo2 class?

Comment: `Foo3 derp = new Foo3()` isn't working?

Comment: by any chance, is foo3 supposed to be derived from foo2?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention foo2 is already instantiated succesfully...

Comment: Shouldn't it be ((foo2)newDoc).my3rdFoo? Is this copied from code you're actually using?

Comment: There's no related to object instantiation in your code. There's only cast.

Comment: Right its a cast!  But can I self-instantiate foo3 somehow?  I know it's null because I never called a new on foo3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first instantiate a class that derives your abstract class, in your case - foo2. Then, you assign a new object to the one you want to instantiate:

```
var myFoo2 = new foo2();
myFoo2.my3rdFoo = new foo3();
```

OR using object instantiation syntax:

```
var myFoo2 = new foo2{
  my3rdFoo = new foo3()
};
```

OR add my3rdFoo instantiation to foo2 constructor:

```
public foo2(){
  my3rdFoo = new foo3();
}
```

You cannot instantiate abstract class directly.

Only after this, you can assign values to subclass'es properties. 
Also, you should name classes in uppercase - will be easier to differentiate later on.

Comment: Why put the my3rdFoo instantiation in `foo2`'s constructor instead of in `foo`'s?

Comment: I would like to know why as well.

Comment: Actually, it was just a personal preference :) You can do it either way - just choose the one that is the most suitable to your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class foo
{
     public string myId {get;set;}
     public string mystring {get;set;}
     public foo3 my3rdFoo {get;set}
}

class foo2 : foo
{
     public string myFavoriteFoo {get;set;}
}

class foo3:foo2
{
     public string myName{get;set}         
}
```

Instantiate using

```
Foo3 myThirdFoo = new foo3();
string result = foo3.myName;
```

If you want to access the third foo from inside foo2 then use this code

```
abstract class foo
{
     public string myId {get;set;}
     public string mystring {get;set;}
     public foo3 my3rdFoo {get;set}
}

class foo2 : foo
{
     public foo3 myFavoriteFoo {get;set;}
}

class foo3
{
     public string myName{get;set}         
}
```

And use as follows

```
foo3 ThirdFoo = new foo3();
ThirdFoo.myName = "Something nice";

foo2 SecondFoo = new foo2(){myFavouriteFoo = ThirdFoo};
String Result = SecondFoo.myFavouriteFoo.myName;
```

yet another way would be

```
 abstract class foo
    {
         public string myId {get;set;}
         public string mystring {get;set;}
         public foo3 my3rdFoo {get;set}
    }

    class foo2 : foo
    {
         public foo3 myFavoriteFoo {get;set;}

         public foo2(string myName)
         {
             foo3 = new foo3();
             foo3.myName = myName;

         }

    }

    class foo3
    {
         public string myName{get;set}         
    }
```

And then access it using

```
foo2 SecondFoo = new foo2("Something nice");
String Result = SecondFoo.myfavouritefoo.myName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to instantiate any objects in the constructor. So given your code, I would initialize its "foo3" in the default constructor of the base class.

```
abstract class foo
{
     public foo() { this.my3rdFoo = new foo3(); }
     public string myId {get;set;}
     public string mystring {get;set;}
     public foo3 my3rdFoo {get;set}
}

class foo2 : foo
{
     public string myFavoriteFoo {get;set;}
}

class foo3
{
     public string myName{get;set}         
}
```

Comment: Unless `foo3` is `IDisposable` or an unmanaged resource (neither of which is the case here), it really doesn't make sense to make the base class disposable.

Comment: Im curious what is the difference between instantiating in the abstract vs instantiating in foo2?

Comment: @ENC0D3D No difference in how the foo2 class is used. But if another class inherited from the base foo, then it would also need to to instantiate the base class's member. IMO, better to make sure each class knows how to manage it's own resources, and not depend on child classes to become properly instantiated. Child classes could always override the base class's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiation should look something like this

```
foo2 newDoc = new foo2();

newDoc.myId = "123";
newDoc.mystring = "Hey";

newDoc.my3rdFoo = new foo3(); //move this to a constructor foo() if you would like
newDoc.my3rdFoo.myName = "blah...blah...";
```

You cannot do `((foo2)newDoc).foo3.myName`. Instead it needs to be `newDoc.my3rdFoo.myName`

because `foo3` is a class whereas `my3rdFoo` is an instance of `foo3` class whose property you can set.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate the `foo3` object in the constructor of `foo`:

```
abstract class foo
{
     public string myId {get;set;}
     public string mystring {get;set;}
     public foo3 my3rdFoo {get;set}
     public foo()
     {
          this.my3rdFoo = new foo3();
     }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
foo newDoc = new foo2();
newDoc.my3rdFoo.myName = "blah...blah...";
```

And you should consider capitalizing your classes and properties so that you match the [C# conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002.aspx).